# React Native: How can i fetch Data instant when or before the screen is rendered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i did it this way but now i need to safe the file before the function gets called. i need it to get called instant when the user swapps into the screen because the items that will be shown are coming from the fetch.

```html
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    async function getUserData() {
      var ingredients = await firebase.firestore().doc("ingredients/" + user.uid).get();
      var labels = []
      ingredients.data().ingredients.forEach(ingredient => {
        labels.push(ingredient.label)
      })
      setUserIngredients(labels)
      console.log(userIngredients)
      setUserRecipes([])
    }
    getUserData()
    fetchRecipes(userIngredients)
  }, [])
```

here is the fetchRecipes function

```html
function fetchRecipes(userIngredients) {
    var number = 5
    var url = "https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/findByIngredients?ingredients=" + userIngredients.join(",") + "&number=" + String(number) + "&apiKey=" + apiKey
    fetch(url, {
      method: "GET"
    }).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
          var newRecipe = {
            id: responseJson[i].id,
            title: responseJson[i].title,
            image: responseJson[i].image,
            ingredients: userIngredients
          }
          userRecipes.unshift(newRecipe)
        }
        firebase.firestore().doc("ingredients/" + user.uid).update({
          recipes: userRecipes
        })
        console.log("Rezepte", userRecipes)
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some changes needed:

1. you may change react hook that you used, better use useEffect hook, as you didnt work with any dom mutation there
2. you may implement custom hook

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const useFetch = (targetUrl) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const response = await fetch(targetUrl);
      const json = await response.json();
      setData(json);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [targetUrl]);

  return data;
};

const App = () => {
    const URL = 'https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/findByIngredients?ingredients=" + userIngredients.join(",") + "&number=" + String(number) + "&apiKey=" + apiKey';
    const result = useFetch(URL);

    return (
      <div>
        {JSON.stringify(result)}
      </div>
    );
}
```